# creating sprite kit game in swift. adding a character to the scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am creating a game and I set up the background already. Now when I put in the code to add the character to the scene it does not appear. This is the code I used to try and get the character to appear on the screen. Apparently my character shows up behind the background. Is there another way to get the character to show in front of the background?

```
 func createPlayer() -> SKNode {

    let playerNode = SKNode()


        playerNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 80.0)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pig")
        playerNode.addChild(sprite) return playerNode }
```

Comment: try using:  zPosition

Comment: Have you added playerNode to the scene?

Comment: @SteveIves I did but when i run it, it still comes up behind the background

Comment: @Abdou023 i will try that

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the character appear in front of the background image you need to use zposition:

```
//You need to choose a high zposition number to make sure it shows up in front.

    playerNode.zPosition = 1
// you should set the background images z position using the same method to something below 1
```

I would also recommend using this to add your character to the scene:

```
self.addChild(playerNode)
```